# Unresolved reference: HiltTestApplication error

Tags: android, testing

I'm trying to create a HiltTestRunner class for testing with Hilt. Here is the code:

```
package com.example.newsworld.application

import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context
import androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner

class HiltTestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {

    override fun newApplication(
        cl: ClassLoader?,
        className: String?,
        context: Context?
    ): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, HiltTestApplication::class.java.name, context)
    }
}
```

The problem is that for HiltTestApplication it shows an error saying `Unresolved reference: HiltTestApplication`. Then in *Show Context Options* it gives me an option to `Add library 'Gradle: com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.44@arr' to classpath`, but nothing happens if I click on it. I've added the following dependencies:

```
implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")
kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")
androidTestImplementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.44'
kaptAndroidTest 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44'
```

Project level build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version "2.44" apply false
}

ext {
    activityVersion = '1.4.0'
    appCompatVersion = '1.4.0'
    constraintLayoutVersion = '2.1.2'
    coreTestingVersion = '2.1.0'
    coroutines = '1.5.2'
    lifecycleVersion = '2.5.1'
    materialVersion = '1.4.0'
    roomVersion = '2.5.0'
    // testing
    junitVersion = '4.13.2'
    espressoVersion = '3.4.0'
    androidxJunitVersion = '1.1.3'
}
```

App level build.gradle file plugins:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}
```

Comment: In my dependencies, I changed `androidTestImplementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.44'` to `debugImplementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.44'`. I don't know why but it worked.